# Working with a ResultSet

Tags: java

I am trying to get a count from a particular table in my derby database, but when I run the code I keep getting Invalid operation at current cursor position

```
    public int getNumUsers(){
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int size = -1;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from USERS");
        while(rs.next()){
            size = rs.getInt("COUNT");
        }
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        sqe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Or chnge your line to `rs.getInt(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give an **alias** to count(*) in your **select statement**. in **mysql** we use `as` to give alias name.I dunno about derby though, but think it'd be similar.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) as count from USERS");
        while(rs.next()){
            size = rs.getInt("count");
        }
```

Comment: That was the problem, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Change your query to

```
select count(*) As COUNT from USERS
```

or change your function call to

```
rs.getInt(1);
```